# SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'href': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, internet-explorer

This code doesn't work with IE but it does on chrome and firefox.

I get this error message IE console : SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'href': object is null or undefined

```
<script>
$(document).on("ready", alternar_banner);

array_imagen = new Array(2);
array_imagen[0] = new Image(108,225);
array_imagen[0].src = "banner1.gif";
array_imagen[1] = new Image(108,225);
array_imagen[1].src = "banner2.gif";

array_url = new Array(2);
array_url[0] = 'http://www.google.com';
array_url[1] = 'https://www.yahoo.com';

contador = 0;

function alternar_banner(){ 
    window.document["banner"].src = array_imagen[contador].src;
window.document.links["bannerref"].href = array_url[contador];
contador ++;
contador = contador % array_imagen.length; 
setTimeout("alternar_banner()",6000);
}

</script>

<a name="bannerref" href="#"><img src="#" name="banner" width=108 height=225 border=0></a>
```

Comment: The relevant HTML code is missing.

Comment: is there a link with the id `bannerref` in your DOM & if there is, is there a href tag to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.links) returns a collection of anchors with an href attribute, if you don't have an `href` attributes associated to the anchor it wont return it as a part of the collection.

> The links property returns a collection of all AREA elements and anchor elements in a document with a value for the href attribute.

So it could be couple of things:

- The id/name of the element you are looking for is not `bannerref`.
- It doesn't have an `href` attribute.

*Update* after question update of markup

It seems like `document.links` in IE needs to be referred using index i.e ex: `window.document.links[0].href` but you cannot rely on that since there culd be many more anchors appearing before that. Instead try use the below if that is the only instance of anchor with the name:

```
 document.getElementsByName("bannerref")[0].href = array_url[contador];
```

or give an id for that anchor as `bannerref`:

```
document.getElementById("bannerref").href = array_url[contador];
```

or you can also use jquery to fetch the element and set the attribute to it.

and better use the practice of giving the function reference for `setTimeout`

i.e

```
   setTimeout(alternar_banner,6000);
```

Comment: Thanks to all.

PSL, I did what you suggest and now it's working.

Like you said, I give and id and use getElementById, thank you very much for the tip.